# How do I Increase size of Argument list in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, spark-submit

When using the following command an error related to argument list size occurs.

```
Spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --py-files /home/user/sandbox/ldsm/ldsm.py --input s3://bucket1/file1
```

Error message:

```
Spark-submit failed while reading data from s3 on EMR.

Spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --py-files /home/user/sandbox/ldsm/ldsm.py --input s3://bucket1/file1 s3://bucket1/file2...s3://bucket1/file900 parameter ( --input) has 900 arguments

The length of argument list is 170 kb

It failed with /bin/bash : Arguments too long
```

I was wondering how I could increase the size of Argument list.

Comment: Path args using double-quotes to prevent bash expansion "s3://bucket1/file1".

Answer (score 0):

Path args using double-quotes to prevent bash expansion "s3://bucket1/file1"